# php codeigniter fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe<

Tags: php, codeigniter

getting following error on send mail with codeigniter email library

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message:  fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed
>   with errno=32 Broken pipe
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 2242

my config:

```
$config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl host';   
$config['smtp_port']    = '465';                    
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
$config['smtp_user']    = 'username';
$config['smtp_pass']    = 'password';
$config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']    = "\r\n";
$config['mailtype'] = 'html'; 
$config['validation'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Could you try to change `$config['smtp_port']` to `25`?

Comment: tried with 25.no success. same code workes with other project.

Comment: also tried with tls settings.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem with an email provider that upgraded their services to have tighter TLS security requirements. The error was the result of the remote connection being forced closed due to a TLS protocol/cipher rejection.

In your case it is very possible your SMTP provider doesn't support SSL on port 465. It's more common to use TLS over port 587 or port 25. Try TLS over port 587 and make sure your config is actually using TLS. Your hostname sometimes has to begin with "tls://" to signal that need.